# Error while trying to use MOTChallenge devkit

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am having an error while trying to use the MOTChallenge devkit.

My code is as follows

```
benchmarkDir = '../data/2DMOT2015/train/';
allMets = evaluateTracking('c2-train.txt', 'res/data/', benchmarkDir);
```

And I have my data in the right folder but Matlab is throwing me an error

```
Reading ground truth...
Error using sparse
sparse(A) does not accept char inputs A.  Use sparse(double(A)) instead.

Error in convertTXTToStruct (line 108)
    stInfo.W=sparse(stInfo.W);


Error in evaluateTracking (line 66)
    gtI = convertTXTToStruct(groundTruth);


Error in test (line 2)
    allMets = evaluateTracking('c2-train.txt', 'res/data/', benchmarkDir);
```

Please help.
The MOTChallenge devkit can be found here https://motchallenge.net/devkit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the lines:

```
stInfo.W=sparse(stInfo.W);
stInfo.H=sparse(stInfo.H);
```

with:

```
stInfo.W=sparse(double(stInfo.W));
stInfo.H=sparse(double(stInfo.H));
```

It worked perfectly for me

Comment: Thanks :) That was a simple fix.